# How to check the UITextField for specific numbers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a simple addition and subtraction app. It randomizes the first number, operation, and second number. Everything is fine until input.  Suppose the done key did work I would like to know how to compare what the user entered with the right answer and if it is wrong, then make the user reenter an answer. Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var firstNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var operation: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secondNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var equals: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var check: UITextField!

var result = Int()
var number1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
var operationRandom = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
var number2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
var op = "+"
var wrong = "wrong"
@IBAction fund enter(sender: AnyObject) { //linked to the UITextField

    if operationRandom == 0{
        result = number1 - number2

    }else{
        result = number1 + number2
    }

    if check.text == "\(result)"{
         number1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
         operationRandom = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
         number2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
    }else{
        check.placeholder = "Wrong"
        }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    firstNumber.text = "\(number1)"
    secondNumber.text = "\(number2)"
    if operationRandom == 0{
        operation.text = "-"

    }else{
        operation.text = "+"
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: I need the answer to the second question. I would like to know how to compare what the user entered with the right answer, and suppose it is wrong, then make the user reenter an answer, but if it is right then give another random problem.

Comment: I don't know how to compare the UITextField text to the actual result of the addition/subtraction of the equation and if it's wrong reenter another answer.

Comment: Is this short enough or must I make it even shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just forgot to set the text and labels to the new values, and clear the check field before setting the placeholder to "Wrong".

```
if check.text == "\(result)"{
     number1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
     operationRandom = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
     number2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
     firstNumber.text = "\(number1)"
     secondNumber.text = "\(number2)"
}else{
    check.text = ""
    check.placeholder = "Wrong"
}
```

Comment: This might work if I had the keyboard problem fixed. Once I fix the keyboard and make it go down then I will check this if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I got the keyboard working and this solution almost worked. I just needed to clear check.text if the answer is right :) Thanks for the help.